# How to use a JS variable which is passed to ejs template for angular app?

Tags: angularjs, ejs

Given an EJS template which is rendered with expressJS, I have a variable `itemId`. How can I use it in the `MyCtrl` controller?

```
<script>x="<%=itemId%>"</script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

</div>
```

So far I have tried

```
<script>$scope.x=<%=itemId%></script>
```

and then in the controller, try to fetch it with `$scope.x` but it does not work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may need to add quotes around your var if it is a string or zero padded number.

```
<script>x="<%=itemId%>";</script>
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">

</div>
```

Also, you need to set it to your `$scope`'d value (in your controller).  Assuming you have your controller in another JS file somewhere else in your code

```
function MyCtrl($scope){
    $scope.x = window.x;
}
```